# Difference Nslookup vs. ping -a

Tags: windows-7, dns, ping, nslookup

We are trying to setup reverse look-up zones in our Windows environment.  Prior to setting up the zones, nslookup would fail to resolve an IP to hostname.  Oddly ping -a  would resolve a hostname.  Does ping -a use a different method such as netbios to resolve a hostname?

Comment: "Does ping -a use a different method such as netbios to resolve a hostname?" Yes. :)

Comment: Do you know where this is documented by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nslookup consults only the DNS server configured, while ping -a uses additional methods like NETBIOS to resolve the name. If both computers are in the same network segment, they use broadcast messages to exchange host names without a DNS server, so ping -a works and nslookup doesnot.